# How does Craft regard a Lightswitch field when it's set to Required in the Fields layout?

Tags: user-profile, lightswitch, required

If I set a Lightswitch field as required, does that require it to be On? Is that valid at all?

(Context: I'm using a Lightswitch in User fields to capture "I agree to the Terms & Conditions...", and building a front-end user registration form.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently it has no affect on the Lightswitch field at all, which I think is the right call.

However, you do have a valid use-case for either making a setting on the field that forced it to be "on" if required is set or maybe even a separate "Require On" field type all-together.

Regardless, probably worth putting up on http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com